# Mysql inner join have same row as the selected table

Tags: mysql

Hello i have two tables.
1)questions
2)users

they both have `id` row. now how can i to only read the `id` row from table questions.

```
SELECT id
     , title
     , body
     , x.cdate
     , tags
     , pic
     , username 
  FROM asks x
  JOIN accounts y
    ON y.id = x.userid 
 ORDER 
    BY x.cdate DESC
```

that is what i tried to do. and its didn`t work.

Comment: Can you supply sample data and desired results?

Comment: In your question you have table questions and users, but in your query you have asks and accounts. Not only because of this, your question is unclear.

Comment: When you say "they both have id row" do you really mean they both have id columns?

Comment: Specify what table you want to show the `id`column from by adding the table as prefix just as you did for `x.cdate`in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to type the it like this: id.one of the tables.
Example:
(id.accounts)
be carefull that you not select the other table with table.*

Answer (score 0):

the given query shows all the asked questions. you also selected to shoe accounts.id in your query which is equal to asks.userid, both are equal at each row of the join table. there is nothing wrong here it seems you want to show the username and user picture for each question. so either i don't understand what your problem is or there may be some other issue with the tables.